# Can you get the parent GTK window from a widget?

Tags: widget, window, gtk

I have a custom widget and it needs to launch a MessageDialog and in order for me to put that message dialog on top of the window my widget is in then I need access to the parent gtk.window. Is there a way to get the parent GTK window? Thanks

Answer (score 15):

The GTK docs suggest:

```
   GtkWidget *toplevel = gtk_widget_get_toplevel (widget);
   if (gtk_widget_is_toplevel (toplevel))
     {
       /* Perform action on toplevel. */
     }
```

get_toplevel will return the topmost widget you're inside, whether or not it's a window, thus the is_toplevel check. Yeah something is mis-named since the code above does a "get_toplevel()" then an immediate "is_toplevel()" (most likely, get_toplevel() should be called something else).

Comment: Gtk docs (below) seem to suggest to call `GTK_IS_WINDOW()` on the result, not `gtk_widget_is_toplevel()`

https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtk/gtk3/method.Widget.get_toplevel.html

Answer (score 8):

In pygtk, you can get the toplevel like `toplevel = mywidget.get_toplevel()` then feed `toplevel` directly to `gtk.MessageDialog()`

Answer (score 7):

For GTK4, the `gtk_widget_get_toplevel()` method on `GtkWidget` has been deprecated. Instead, you can use the `gtk_widget_get_root()` method or the `Widget:root` property, which returns a `GtkRoot`. That `GtkRoot` can then be cast to a `GtkApplicationWindow()` or `GtkWindow()`.

Here's an example in C

```
GtkRoot *root = gtk_widget_get_root (GTK_WIDGET (widget));
GtkWindow *window = GTK_WINDOW (root);
```

Here's an example in Rust

```
let window: Window = widget
    .root()
    .unwrap()
    .downcast::<Window>()
    .unwrap();
```

Answer (score 5):

Though gtk_widget_get_toplevel should work, you may also give a try to the code below. It should get the parent gtk window for the given widget and print it's title.

```
GdkWindow *gtk_window = gtk_widget_get_parent_window(widget);
GtkWindow *parent = NULL;
gdk_window_get_user_data(gtk_window, (gpointer *)&parent);
g_print("%s\n", gtk_window_get_title(parent));
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: This takes a needless detour through low-level GDK gunge - better to stay with the GTK layer. Here you require the widget to be realized, and will likely have issues in GTK 3.

Comment: "though the proper recommended method should work, you might also try this needlessly complex alternative for no discernible reason"... or is there one...?