# How to get parent Gtk::Window from inside derived widget class?

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I have a class inheriting from `Gtk::Box` so I can create multiple instances of it at runtime and add them dynamically to a `Gtk::Notebook`.

However if there is a critical error, I want to pop up a message that won't disappear behind the main window, so I need to get the parent window from within my derived `Gtk::Box` class.

Going off [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098316/can-you-get-the-parent-gtk-window-from-a-widget) (which is for GTK, not for gtkmm), I have done this:

```
Gtk::Container *parent = this->get_toplevel();
if (parent->get_is_toplevel()) {
    Gtk::MessageDialog dlg(*parent, "blah");
    dlg.run();
}
```

However I get an error telling me there is "no known conversion from Gtk::Container to Gtk::Window".

Am I supposed to use a `dynamic_cast<>` to typecast the `Gtk::Container` into a `Gtk::Window`?  If so, is it unnecessary to call `get_is_toplevel()`? (Because that's kind of the same as checking the result of the `dynamic_cast<>`).

Or is there a different way this should be done in gtkmm?

Comment: `static_cast<Gtk::Window>` seems to work, so there might not be a need for `dynamic_cast`. I guess `dynamic` is theoretically safer though, but `static` is probably fine as long as you know for sure the toplevel is a `Window`, which I do. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this works, but I've no idea whether it's correct or not:

```
Gtk::Window *parent = dynamic_cast<Gtk::Window *>(this->get_toplevel());
if (parent) {
    Gtk::MessageDialog dlg(*parent, "blah");
    dlg.run();
}
```

Comment: `static_cast<Gtk::Window>` seems to work, so there might not be a need for `dynamic_cast`. I guess `dynamic` is theoretically safer though.